# C# compare values of properies in different collections

Tags: c#, linq, list, compare

I have some class:

```
public class AddressInfoes
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public int RegionID { get; set; }
}
```

and class:

```
public class Regions
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RegionName { get; set; }
    public int RegionID { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying create method for find `Region` of `List<AddressInfoes>` equals `RegionName` in IEnumerable:

```
private bool RegionCheck(List<AddressInfoes> addresses, IEnumerable<Regions> regions)
{
    return regions.Any(x=>addresses.Any()y=>y.Region.Equals(x.RegionName));
}
```

But this method not work correctly? 
How I can implement?

I need compare by two properties:

```
  var result = addresses.Where(reg => !regions.Any(y => y.RegionName.Equals(reg.Region.Trim(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            && addresses.Where(reg => !regions.Any(y => y.RegionDomainID == reg.RegionDomainID)));
```

But I have error:

Error   1   A local variable named 'reg' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'reg', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else C:\TEMP\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs  89  39  MultipartFormData

Comment: Are you trying to find the regions or if there are any regions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
regions.Where(x => addresses.Any(addr => addr.Region == x.RegionName));
//.ToList() or .Any();
```

Comment: @user2469940 - Either put `.Any()` at the end or change, the `Where` to `Any`

Answer (score 2):

I have this code, maybe it's overkill but it's generic:

```
    public static bool IsEquivalent<T, TU>(this ICollection<T> collection, ICollection<TU> sourceCollection, Func<T, TU, bool> predicate) where T : class
    {
        var copyCollection = collection.Clone();

        if (copyCollection.Count == 0 && !sourceCollection.Any()) return true;
        foreach (var source in sourceCollection)
        {
            var element = copyCollection.FirstOrDefault(x => predicate(x, source));
            if (element == null) return false;
            copyCollection.Remove(element);
        }
        return !copyCollection.Any();
    }

    public static ICollection<T> Clone<T>(this ICollection<T> listToClone)
    {
        var array = new T[listToClone.Count];
        listToClone.CopyTo(array, 0);
        return array.ToList();
    }
```

And you can call it like:

```
regions.IsEquivalent(regions2, (x,y)=>x.Region==y.RegionName);
```

regions are `AddressInfoes` and regions2 are `Regions`

This method returns `bool`. When collections are equivalent -> same size and all items match according to predicate it's returning `true`

Answer (score 2):

```
bool isEqual = addresses.Select(a=>a.Region).Distinct().OrderBy(x=>x)
              .SequenceEqual(regions.Select(r=>r.RegionName).Distinct().OrderBy(x=>x));
```